# Simple question about a cocos2d based game template

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I am learning a cocos2d based Game template tutorial from [here](http://timroadley.com/) and now I am at [this point](http://timroadley.com/2011/08/02/game-template-part-5-level-selection/) of the tutorial. My question is, how can i run 30 different scenes in 30 different levels of 5 chapter? Now I am using this

```
switch (gameData.selectedLevel) {

    case 1:

    [SceneManager goChapter1Level1Scene];

    break;

    (... snip a whole lot of lines...)

    case 30:

    [SceneManager goChapter5Level6Scene];

    break;

    default: break;

}
```

in the "- (void) onPlay: (CCMenuItemImage*) sender" method. But it work only for 6 levels scene of chapter1. Other 4 chapters levels are show as same as 1st chapter levels scene. they are not show their own level scene. can any one please teach me, how can I do this stuff using this game template?

Comment: Just a code comment: If you have 30 different methods where the only difference is the numbers they take, and you're not doing `goChapterLevel(5, 6)` you either know exactly what you're doing or you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: I would love to know the case for "know exactly what your doing".  Seriously, I would.

Comment: @nycynik On second thought there probably isn't one.

Comment: That makes me feel better :) TY

Comment: First four words of your question aren't actually needed, I suggest that you try to make your question titles less verbose and more concrete. Just my opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a total guess here, but it seems like your calculation of selectedLevel might be wrong.  How are you calculating it?  Is it someting like Chapter*Level?  I would check that your not just sending level, and so when the chapter changes it fails to change.